# With the toolbox container tool, can I run an Ubuntu toolbox on top of a Fedora host?

Tags: podman, toolbox

https://github.com/containers/toolbox is a system for integrating containers more closely with a host environment, so that you can switch into a toolbox, automatically give it access to your home directory, and install some compilers.

Can toolbox be used to install Ubuntu on top of a Fedora [Silverblue] host? The default configuration doesn't know about the `--distro Ubuntu`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the `toolbox create` command has a `--image` option, so you could try running:

```
toolbox create --image docker.io/ubuntu:22.10 ubuntu-toolbox
```

And that *almost* works, except that `toolbox` seems to really want the `capsh` command to be available inside the container. So if we use the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM docker.io/ubuntu:22.10

RUN apt-get update; apt-get -y install libcap2-bin; apt-get clean
```

And build an `ubuntu-toolbox` image:

```
podman build -t ubuntu-toolbox .
```

And then create a toolbox:

```
toolbox create --image ubuntu-toolbox ubuntu-toolbox
```

We can now enter our toolbox:

```
$ grep NAME /etc/os-release
NAME="Fedora Linux"
VERSION_CODENAME=""
PRETTY_NAME="Fedora Linux 37 (Workstation Edition)"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:fedoraproject:fedora:37"
DEFAULT_HOSTNAME="fedora"
$ toolbox enter ubuntu-toolbox
$ grep NAME /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.10"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_CODENAME=kinetic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=kinetic
```